# Changing values of array of objects using underscore

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have the following object:

```
Object x - is an array of objects which look like below:
     name: "test1"
     value: Array[3]
        0: "string1"
        1: "string2"
        2: "string3"
     name: "test2"
     value: Array[3]
        0: "string1"
        1: "string2"
        2: "string3"
```

and so on..

I want to iterate through the objects in x and modify the values by appending string to each of them, so result would be like:

```
    name: "test1"
    value: Array[3]
        0: "string1appended"
        1: "string2appended"
        2: "string3appended"
```

I've tried the following but it seems inefficient:

```
.each(x, function(x1) {.each(x1, function(x2) {
    _.map(x2, function(i) {
      return i + "appended";
    })
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

My version doesn't require `map`:

```
_.each(arr, function (el) {
  _.each(el.value, function (v, i) {
    el.value[i] += 'appended';
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
 _.each(x,function(obj){
   obj.value = obj.value.join('appended ').concat('appended').split(' ');
 });
```

```js
var x = [{
   name: "test1",
   value: ["string1", "string2", "string3"]
 }, {
   name: "test2",
   value: ["string1", "string2", "string3"]
 }];
 _.each(x, function(obj) {
   obj.value = obj.value.join('appended ').concat('appended').split(' ');
 });
 console.log(x);
```

Answer (score -1):

So the solution was:

```
_.each(x, function(x1){x1.value = _.map(x1.value, function(x2) { return x2+'appended'})})
```